# TextFile overwritten, sometime not

Tags: c#, text-files

I make a function where a textfile been generated when the address of the PLC turn to true it will generate the text file with info such as lot ID, operator ID and unit ID in it, and when it runs through the code again, it will overwrite the text file with the updated data/value. But the problem is, sometimes the text file is updated, and sometimes it's not. If I delete the existing file, it will take some time to generate a new one or won't generate a new one at all. I only use one line of the code. I'm still new with this. Hope anyone can help to solve this. Thanks.

Here is my code  :

```
if (iOPC.Read<bool>(Utilities.OpcAddress.visionRead_Trigger_TxtFile) == true)
{
       File.WriteAllText(settingFile.VisionFilePath, string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", lotID_TxtFile_Naneye, operatorID_TxtFile_NanEye, unitID_TxtFile_NanEye));
}
lotID_TxtFile_Naneye = iOPC.Read<string>(Utilities.OpcAddress.lotID_Current_TxtFile);
operatorID_TxtFile_NanEye = iOPC.Read<string>(Utilities.OpcAddress.operatorID_Current_TxtFile);
unitID_TxtFile_NanEye = iOPC.Read<string>(Utilities.OpcAddress.unitID_TxtFIle);
```

Comment: The code is writing data from memory to a file. if the variables are empty, you will get nothing in the file. However, if the file is not generated, this may be due to an error. You should use try/catch to display the error. Every time this code executes, it will overwrite the file. You say it takes long time....I am not aware of what OPC is but this may have to do with network stuff. Try debugging using VS.

Comment: Well you have a _guard_ condition there possibly preventing the file being created. _"sometimes the textfile is updated, and sometimes its not"_ is not surprising

Comment: @NoChance thanks. I done that and finally found out the reason of the error. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note: Based on your comment, I have "promoted" the note to an answer so that it does not appear as an un-answered question.

The code is writing data from memory to a file. if the variables are empty, you will get nothing in the file. However, if the file is not generated, this may be due to an error. You should use try/catch to display the error. Every time this code executes, it will overwrite the file. You say it takes long time....I am not aware of what OPC is but this may have to do with network stuff. Try debugging using VS.